# Automatic line wrap/return carriage in Zebra printers with CPCL

Tags: zebra-printers

I am printing with a Zebra printer MZ 320 over bluetooth. I have some texts that can be wider than the paper and I want them to be printed in several lines. Right now, when the text exceeds the page width it is just printed overlapping the previous printed text on the same line. I want the printer to add a carriage return, is there any command to do this?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution?

Comment: @PeterCoulton Sadly not. The only workaround I am aware of is calculating the text length for a specified font, and then keep breaking the string. I seem to remember there was some function for ellipsizing the wider than paper texts.

Comment: can you share some code to overcome this limitation? How you calculate the width of the text

Comment: need you help to find the solution for the same.. If you get time, please [come here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13436/smart-developers-lab) for assistance.